# log4j How to set FileAppender encoding in java code?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, log4j

I tried the following:

```
File logFile = new File("performance.log");
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout, logFile.getName() , false);
appender.setEncoding("UTF-8");
logger.addAppender(appender);

logger.setLevel((Level) Level.DEBUG);
logger.setAdditivity(false);
....
logger.info("Finished in "  + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000 + " \u03BCs");
```

But it does not print the greek mu char correctly. It works if I configure my logger per log4j.properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and just stumbled upon this question. From source code it seems that `FileAppender` does absolutely nothing when you set encoding. The `OutputStreamWriter` with default encoding is already created after calling constructor. It is created only from within `void setFile(String fileName, boolean append, boolean bufferedIO, int bufferSize)` method which is pretty much inconvenient to use, but it gets called from `void activateOptions()`. Anyway, that's what it probably is for!

So if anyone is still having troubles with this, just add this one call and you are good to go:

```
File logFile = new File("performance.log");
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout, logFile.getName() , false);
appender.setEncoding("UTF-8");
appender.activateOptions();
```

Comment: Thank you for `appender.activateOptions();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the XML configuration file:

```xml
<appender name="customLogFile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="encoding" value="Cp1252" />
    ...
</appender>
```